# what gmail use for chat application

Tags: ajax, gmail

i know the ape ajax push engine which can be used for this chat , but i want to know what gmail is using .?

regards

rahul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail uses the [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) protocol for chat.

Comment: is xmpp protocol in chat is implement by common.js ?